# JNLP not loading properly during loadtime

Tags: java, swing, jnlp, java-web-start

I have a Swing app, that I start using JNLP. When I start using JNLP, the UI does not load fully. Like only the top task-bar loads but when the button in the task-bar is clicked, which is used to connect to Database, then the whole app loads properly. It's like only the portion required are loaded rest of the window is blank which is undesirable.

I believe this is not to do with the networking latency since I have my jars in my system itself.

Can somebody help me why this one occurs and how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the app works fine when the missing jar was added

Answer (score 2):

- Ensure all GUI construction & update is performed on the EDT.  See [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details.
- Be sure to check the JNLP using [JaNeLA](http://pscode.org/janela/).

Comment: Follow the link.  The term EDT is expanded on the left hand side of the page in the menus.  You might also have tried 'Java+EDT' in your favorite search engine. All in all, very poor research effort.